# Javascript replace 'null' to 'false' issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var x = [{
    "answer": null,
    "answered": true,
    // many more fields here
    "answers": {
        "correct": null,
        "response": null
    }
}, {
    "answer": null,
    "answered": true,
    // many more fields here
    "answers": {
        "correct": null,
        "response": null
    }
}];

var string = JSON.stringify(x).toString().replace(/\null/g, "false");
var json=jQuery.parseJSON(string);
console.log(json);
```

When I am trying to replace null to false it is not replacing.It will work when you replace other words like "answer" even ":null" is working only null is not working. Can any one explain what is the problem?

Comment: have you tried using `''` instead of `null`?

Comment: You are escaping `\n`. Shouldn't that be `/null/g`. Having said that, this whole thing seems odd.

Comment: @RGraham : /null/g, ":false" shwoing JSON.parse unexpected charecter error

Comment: @amin : '' tried not working

Comment: @FrancisStalin I don't see any JSON.parse in your code? Also, why replace with `":false"` now?

Comment: i have edited can u check now

Answer (score 2):

it's probably better to avoid JSON use but recursive function:

```
function convertNullToFalse(obj){
    for(var k in obj){
        if(obj[k] === null){
            obj[k] = false;
            continue;
        }
        if(typeof obj[k] === "object"){
            convertNullToFalse(obj[k]);
        }
    }
}

convertNullToFalse(x);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: *"Probably"?* Definitely!

Comment: Looked good at first glance, but you have a few typos in there. `obj['k']` should be `obj[k]` and also `obj[k] === false;` should be `obj[k] = false;` :)

Comment: yes we can do like this, my question is why replace function not accepting null to replace

Comment: because you have a '\' before 'null' you can use simple string as pattern : `str.replace("null", "false");`

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping `\n` which is the newline character. You need the literal `n`:

```
var x = [{
    "answer": null,
    "answered": true,
    // many more fields here
    "answers": {
        "correct": null,
        "response": null
    }
}, {
    "answer": null,
    "answered": true,
    // many more fields here
    "answers": {
        "correct": null,
        "response": null
    }
}];

var string = JSON.stringify(x).toString().replace(/null/g, "false");
var thing = jQuery.parseJSON(string);
console.log(thing);
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/AwMaL/)

Also, you're using `JSON.stringify` why not use the inverse `JSON.parse()` too instead of using jQuery?

Finally, why parse this at all? Why not just access answer with a default value:

```
var ans = x.answer || false; // Returns false for any falsey value, including null
```

Comment: [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) say `$.parseJSON` will call `JSON.parse`

Comment: @blgt Why bother though? If you wanted browser support, you wouldn't have used `JSON.stringify`. I had to include the entire jQuery library just for that function in my jsFiddle - maybe OP is wasting the same bandwidth?

Comment: I don't disagree, just saying it's technically the same in OP's case